# Any NTLM challenge-response authentication codes I can embed in my xcode project?

Tags: xcode, authentication, ntlm, smb

I am looking for some NTLM challenge-response authentication codes I can embed in my xcode project (for my iPhone app) so for example, with input of password and 8 bytes of challenge, the code can generate 24 bytes response.

I check samba source code and find that it is impossible for me to cut the part doing NTLM challenge-response authentication and add it to my xcode project. So any other source I can resort to ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [full specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236621%28v=prot.13%29.aspx) is available from Microsoft as an Open Specification.  I'm not aware of an Objective C implementation, so it may be easiest to simply build your own from the specification.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve it.

So first I need to add openssl to my iPhone project b/c I need to MD4 and DES. I am not sure if there is other way to get MD4 & DES. And thankfully someone has already added openssl to xcode, check here http://www.x2on.de/2010/02/01/tutorial-iphone-app-with-compiled-openssl-library/

Then add ntlm implementation upon that. I used the sample code here, http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html

A note though, that sample code has some problem (it took me several hours figured that out). But we can also use keywords there(the function name) to do google code search to find correct implementation.

Comment: For what it's worth - this is the original NTLM, not NTLM2.

Comment: Good to know that. But they said "NTLMv2 is not required by default on most Windows systems. When challenge/response is negotiated, even newer Windows versions will default to using the LM/NTLM combination unless they are specifically configured not to. " -- http://ubiqx.org/cifs/SMB.html   I am adding smb support to my iphone app and it is highly unlikely I will do NTLM2

Comment: I'm not certain when that article was written:  if I recall correctly (and frankly, I may not), Windows Server 2008R2 is the first version where the default is to enforce NTLM2 only (disabling NTLM compatibility.)  But I may be mistaken, and it may be a more subtle difference (Active Directory policies, etc, etc.)  I certainly wouldn't add NTLM2 for the sake of completeness, but if you find yourself unable to authenticate with certain users (>14 character passwords, for example) or to certain servers, I would keep it in mind as a possibility.